# Numpy array size compression or encoding

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, python-imaging-library, data-science

Recently I am working with numpy arrays. I converted the images into arrays using asarray(),then converted the data to 1d array now I have a array of length 1004050.
Can anyone suggest a good method to compress or encode these data ,further minimizing the size of the numpy array?

Comment: Most people use JPEG to compress images... what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am trying to compress the size of the 1d array formed by faltening the numpy array of pixel values of a image.... do you know any such methods to minimize or compress the size of the 1d array formed??

Comment: Yes, I read that in your question! I am suggesting you will get better compression by using JPEG because it takes account of the human eye's characteristics/sensitivities.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Already I'm  using the JPEG formats but still need more compression.....any other ideas from your side???

Comment: Kindly show representative images and the code you used and the sizes you got so I can assist you better. Thank you.

Comment: nope, I was using png since they are much smaller in size when compared to jpeg images, but what we need is a method to compress that data on that numpy array, sir, did you get that? I am trying to encode those NumPy arrays to reduce the length of that array....so anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: You have not shown your images.

Comment: here is the [image](https://github.com/Surya2709/Steganography-With-QR-Codes/blob/main/sampleimages/img.png?raw=true) @MarkSetchell it is about 4kb size

Comment: If I do this `np.asarray(Image.open('compress.png')).flatten().nbytes` with the image you shared, I get 50625 bytes, not the 1004050 in your question....

Comment: yes sir, the qn was asked a year before so i replaced that image with size near 8kb  by this image with size 4kb .....okay anyway sir ...now wegot 50625 bytes sir , so how could i now decrease this  50625 byte into a much smaller size ? that is my question, do we have any methods to compress this much more sir ? so that i can have lesser bytes.